# How to speed up Liquibase execution?

Tags: liquibase, query-performance

I have to update the schema of 20 databases with the same Liquibase changelog. The time requested to create the schema for one empty database is arround 5s. In a subsequent Liquibase update on the same database, it still take 3.6s even if no changes are applied.
Since the Liquibase update is performed 20 times (once per database) the resulting overall execution times (100s and 72s) for either schema creation or schema verification is critical for my use-case.

My Liquibase version is 3.5.5 but I also tried version 3.6.3 for which the results are even a bit worse.

I use a bash script to iterate through my databases and execute the Liquibase update. It looks as follow:

```sh
for i in {1..5}; do
  liquibase --contexts=MT --logLevel=warning \
    --username=sa --password=XXX \
    --url="jdbc:sqlserver://<ip-address>:50179;DatabaseName=db$i" \
    --changeLogFile=/my-changelogs.xml \
    update
done
```

Is there a way to reduce the Liquibase execution time for a single update? Alternatively, is it possible to reduce the overall execution time by running the Liquibase update in parallel or by loading Liquibase classpath only once?

Answer (score 0):

You can run every process in background using `&` and `nohup` that allows to close your terminal without close the process.

The result will be

```
for i in {1..5}; do
  nohup liquibase --contexts=MT --logLevel=warning \
    --username=sa --password=XXX \
    --url="jdbc:sqlserver://<ip-address>:50179;DatabaseName=db$i" \
    --changeLogFile=/my-changelogs.xml \
    update &> nohup$i.out&
done
```